# How to Cast Application Bar Color to a Theme Resource Color

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I would simply like to customize my application bar so that under certain states different default theme colors are used. This is to give a little different feel to the standard application bar. My trouble is setting the foreground and background colors to theme resource colors. I am getting an invalid Cast exception when trying the following

```
ApplicationBar.ForegroundColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneChromeBrush"];
```

and I am not sure why? To note, no explicit error occurs before debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ApplicationBar.ForegroundColor = (Application.Current.Resources["PhoneChromeBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color;
```

because that resource is a brush (hence the name PhoneChromeBrush) therefore you have to convert it to SolidColorBrush first and then get the Color property from it.